# How do I set my cursor position to the end of the EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an EditText text field. When I click it, the cursor is set to wherever the users touch is.

I am aware of this method of setting the selection to the end of the Edit Text:

```
myEditText.setSelection(myEditText.getText().length());
```

The above function works, but it is being overwritten when the user taps the text box. The cursor flashes to the end of the edit text then snaps to wherever the user tapped.

It seems that some event occurs after OnTouch or OnClick which overwrites it.

How do I ensure that when the user clicks on the EditText it stays at the end of the file until another seperate tap?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `onFocusChangeListener` for this, firing a statement once the edittext has the users focus:

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            myEditText.setSelection(myEditText.getText().length());
        }
    }
});
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29

**Update:**

`onTouchListener`? I believe this is more suitable:

```
myEditText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
            myEditText.setSelection(myEditText.getText().length());
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Another option might be to disable focusable touch in the xml in conjunction with one of the listeners:

```
<EditText android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Comment: Still getting the same "snapping to wherever the user clicked" effect

Comment: Updated answer with another solution

Comment: Couldn't make it work, I did find a scrollTo method which has done the trick. Thanks for helping. Answer on other comment

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I placed this in my OnTouch override but it will work anywhere

```
bioEditText.scrollTo(0, bioEditText.getBottom());
```